# Query should return result and count of types?

Tags: solr

Current query example (searching for 'test'):

```
q=lastName:test*^10 firstName:test*^9 userLastNameLowerBoost:test*^8      
  userFirstNameLowerBoost:test*^7 member:test*^6 title:test*^5 
  message:test*&start=0&rows=5
```

Now my solr index got several types of results (persons, messages and so on) and my result just contains the first 5 results ordered by boost. But I also need the count of all kind of types as result (e.g. person count = 40, message count = 54, ..). If I dont limit the query by 'start' and 'rows' I could count that in java but this should not be the sense of pagination (loading whole results). So do I can add a subquery how counts the types (fieldname 'documentType' --> can be 1 = person , 2 = messages, ..).

I hope you undestand what I want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just add `&facet=true&facet.field=documentType&facet.mincount=1` to get counts of documentTypes in the whole index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use field grouping as describe [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing). or, [facet search](http://searchhub.org/2009/09/02/faceted-search-with-solr), it depend on the type of your query

Comment: But this wont worked because my current query limit to 5 results but i want the counts of the whole query result. If I add '&group=true&group.field=documentType' the result of matches also limited..

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field to each of the document and have it populated by the type e.g. PERSON, MESSAGE.
You can then facet on this field which would give you the count for each type within the result set.